# How can I plot a smoothed curve as well as the original data?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add markers to some of my plots using `pointtype`. If I plot data like so:

```
plot "somedata.txt" w linespoint pointtype 6
```

or a function like so:

```
plot cos(x) pointtype 6
```

I get exactly what I want: a line between and a marker on top of all data points. Right now I want to achieve the same, but after "smoothing" out a dataset using `smooth bezier`:

```
plot "somedata.txt" w linespoint pointtype 6 smooth bezier
```

However `pointtype` doesn't seem to do anything. I can set `linecolor`, `linewidth` and `linetype` as before, but not `pointtype`.

Does anyone know of a work-around that can still produce markers on top of a smoothed plot?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue that gnuplot does not plot points on top of a smooth curve. I speculate that since gnuplot is plotting a function derived from the data points, it does not bother putting the point markers on top of the original data points

Note that a bezier curve will not necessarily overlay the original data points.

My workaround would involve plotting the data twice in different ways:

```
plot 'data.txt' with points title 'original data', \
  '' smooth bezier title 'smoothed data'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @andyras. I have this issue a few weeks algo and couldn't find a way to put both, the smoothed curve and the data. Thus, I plotted two series, one with the smoothed curve and another just for the points.

Edit: sorry for adding a new answer. I'm on my phone and couldn't find a way to comment under @andyras answer

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you *can* plot a smoothed curve with points or linespoints, no need for two passes. For some reasons which I don't understand, the order of `smooth bezier` and `w lp pt 6` apparently seems to be important. If `smooth bezier` comes last, you will only get a line without points despite of specifying `w lp pt 6`. If `smooth bezier` is first, you will get the expected result. This behaviour is still he same in gnuplot 5.5.

**Script:** (works for at least gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plot smooth bezier with pointtypes
reset 

set samples 50

plot '+' u 1:(rand(0)) w lp pt 6 lc rgb "grey"                    ti "without smooth", \
     '+' u 1:(rand(0)) w lp pt 6 lc rgb "red" smooth bezier       ti "smooth last", \
     '+' u 1:(rand(0)) smooth bezier w lp pt 6 lc rgb "web-green" ti "smooth first"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]